# Can I use a VPN and then start up a VM and use another VPN

Tags: windows-7, linux, virtualbox, vpn

I haven't tried this and am wondering if it is possible to obfuscate my location further by using a VPN on my Win10 install and then opening a VM such as Ubuntu or Win7 and then run a VPN in that. I'd use the same provider but different locations. Thanks

Comment: This is a question I'd be very interested in knowing how to do. My school provides a free VPN, but then there are things that I do not want associated with my school account. Nothing illegal, but all the same, there are things you don't search at work either, regardless of legality and even if they are not specifically forbidden. So I'd like to then VPN to my home machine and be able to do everything that I do at home.

Answer (score 0):

If they already know who you are (if you pay them they do) then there is really no point, is there?

To an outside observer your VPN traffic is unintelligible either way.

Comment: I would agree, but question is it technologically possible?

Comment: Definitely. Back in 2004, I remember, I used to run a VM with Win/XP for my USB cable modem, which connected to the Internet, and shared that connection out to my Hackintosh host, that shared that out to my Ubuntu workstation, that connected to an OpenVPN at my workplace, from where I used the PPTP VPN for on-site management consoles, in some forgotten part of the world.

Comment: Old skool nice. Btw what were you doing in 04 with a VPN?

Comment: Workplace requirements. _Not leaking_ any company secrets, I suppose.

Comment: @godDLL hypothetically